# How to retrive data into directive (angularjs) from service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tries to get the data from the view to plot a graph using directive. but directive receiving the undefined. Here are the code snippets.

```
View
<div linear-chart chart-data="dataset"></div>

service
myapp.factory('data', function($http) {
  var data = null;

  return function() {
    if (data) {
      return data;
    } else {
      data = $http.get('data/data.json');
      return data;
    }
  };
});

controller:
myapp.controller('ContactListCtrl', function ($scope, data) {

   data().success(function(dataSet) {
        $scope.dataset = dataSet;
   });

});

directive:
myapp.directive('linearChart', function($parse){
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        template:"<svg></svg>",
        scope: {mydata: '=chartData'},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            //var exp = $parse(attrs.chartData);
            var data = attrs.mydata;
            //var data = exp(scope);
            alert(data);   //not able to get the data here  (i get undefined here)
            var pathClass = "path";

            var padding = 20;
            var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 45},
                width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                    return d.id;
                }))
                .range([0, width]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                    return d.frequency;
                }))
                .range([height, 0]);

            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return x(d.id);
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return y(d.frequency);
                });

            var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                .x(x)
                .y(y)
                .on("zoom", zoomed);


            var rawSvg=elem.find('svg');
            var svg = d3.select(rawSvg[0]);
            svg = d3.select(rawSvg[0])
                .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .call(zoom)
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            var make_x_axis = function () {
                return d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(data.length-1);
            };

            var make_y_axis = function () {
                return d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(5);
            };

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(data.length-1);

            svg.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(5);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x grid")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(make_x_axis()
                    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                    .tickFormat(""));

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y grid")
                .call(make_y_axis()
                    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                    .tickFormat(""));

            var clip = svg.append("svg:clipPath")
                .attr("id", "clip")
                .append("svg:rect")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            var chartBody = svg.append("g")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

            chartBody.append("svg:path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line);

            svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", 700)
                .attr("y", 480)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Time (ms)");


            svg.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Frequency");

            function zoomed() {
                console.log(d3.event.translate);
                console.log(d3.event.scale);
                svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
                svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
                svg.select(".x.grid")
                    .call(make_x_axis()
                        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                        .tickFormat(""));
                svg.select(".y.grid")
                    .call(make_y_axis()
                        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                        .tickFormat(""));
                svg.select(".line")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", line);
            }


        }
    };
});
```

Thanks, please help me regarding this i tries all the possible ways but i didnt get the graph. iam getting the svg but not the graph. let me know how to receive the data from the view.
Once again thanks.

Comment: so mydata is in scope. but giving promise object and having resolve: false. so i did like this instead of  var data = attrs.mydata; var data = exp(scope); alert(data); i put scope.mydata.$promise.then(function(data){ var data = data; console.log(data);});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do no need to 'parse' your attribute using `$parse` since you use two-way data binding. It will be available on the 'scope'. You can read more about isolated scope in the doc and the meaning of '=', '&' and '@': https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Here is an updated plunkr in which I fixed a lot of things. A `$watch` is required since data is received async.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1SLHyNMiOw1swRmXYRI4

Update the `getData()` accordingly to make it work as needed.

Comment: Have you tried my new plunkr? Is your issue solved or do you still need help?

Comment: thanks for reply. i seen your code but i done in different way using promise.

Comment: Please respond to your own question to share your code with the community and then accept your answer to have this 'closed' thx

Comment: like scope.mydata.$promise.then(function(data){ var data = data; console.log(data);}); this is the way i did this.

Answer (score 0):

Your data will be on the scope, instead.  Try this:

```
var data = scope.mydata;
```

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle or Plunk for this?

Comment: No. running on local server

Comment: I meant maybe create an example in JSFiddle or Plunker so that its easier for others to help debug what's going on.

Comment: Here is the link to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sumancreater/hto5cfb2/ thanks

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be setup correctly.  Please get it to actually run, displaying your error.  Its easier to help that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $watch on the scope data in directive.

```
$scope.$watch('mydata', function() {
    // call you chart data draw function here
}, true);
```